# "is let know" or "is let known"?

Tags: grammar

> When he is later let **know** about it, he will act quickly.

or

> When he is later let **known** about it, he will act quickly.

Comment: Was let know. I would prefer "was told".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You said "was let know". Does that mean that "is let know" cannot be used? I need exactly "let know" structure instead of "told" because in my situation it  was not a case of verbal communication.

Comment: "Tell" is not restricted to verbal communication. "Communicate information to someone in spoken or written words." - Oxford Dictionary (Lexico). Example: "The president's son was told in an email that the Russian government wanted to help Donald J. Trump's election bid last year." - the New York Times.

Answer (score 2):

"Let" is rarely used as a passive.  We say "They let us enter" but not "We were let enter".  ("Let go" is sometimes passive, colloquially: "He was let go" means he was dismissed from employment.)

"Let know" is likewise rare in the passive.  We rarely say "I was let know".  It is more idiomatic to say "I was told" or "I was informed" or "They let me know" (etc).